# Set Security Context within AuthenticationSuccessEvent Listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on a web application that uses Spring Security.  We are using a legacy database system, so it was necessary to write a custom `AuthenticationProvide`r.  After successful authentication, we can load info on the user, e.g. roles, available domains, etc.  While this logic can be contained within the `AuthenticationProvider`, we have good reasons to factor it out to an external location.  To do so, I wrote a listener for the Spring Security `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    Authentication auth = event.getAuthentication();
    User user = (User)auth.getPrincipal(); //Custom UserDetails implementation
    List<GrantedAuthority> newAuthorities;

    //Do stuff to user and get new authorities
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
              new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, newAuthorities);
}
```

The `SecurityContext` is changed within the method, but then I seem to lose the new authorities afterwards.  In particular, within the method, the `SecurityContext` contains

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@70df1ce8
```

At the end of the filter chain, I get the message that

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbe0f021
```

is being persisted by `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`.

I may be able to work around this by just putting the logic the `AuthenticationProvider`, customizing the Authentication Filter, or trying to use `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead.  But I'd still like to understand why the changes made in the event handler aren't reflected outside of it.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` as a trigger to reset the `SecurityContext` it might be that the event is fired in an async mode (depending on your config). It really belongs in the `UserDetailsService` which you normally use to retrieve the user and the roles. Looks to me as if you modified to much (but that is from quite a distance).

Comment: Yeah, we've had to do a lot of customization to deal with the peculiarities of our database.  As such, I wasn't really using `UserDetailsService` because our authentication flow diverges from the standard Spring Security approach.  Nevertheless, it might be a good idea to follow their approach more closely to avoid problems like this one.

Comment: Could you describe your flow in a bit more detail? Could be helpful to point you to the right components.

Comment: Sure.  We use a plugin based architecture, and each plugin may or may not need to authenticate the user with its own database server.  So, we have a master `AuthenticationProvider` that iterates through the plugins and calls the `AuthenticationProvider` for each plugin that provides one.

Comment: For at least one of the plugins, the `AuthenticationProvider` has to call a login function on the database server with information from the authentication that was passed in.  The login returns a session token for the user, which is then used for future database access.  As such, we can't really get any user details until after the login is called.

Comment: What I've done so far is to write a Master `UserDetailsService` that is used in the master `AuthenticationProvider` after successful authentication.  It delegates to plugin specific `UserDetailsService` implementations to load the user's roles and available domains for that plugin.  This is n not the standard Spring Security way of using the `UserDetailsService` but it seems to be working for our application.